# Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysql_driver::inset() in Code Igniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, codeigniter

Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysql_driver::inset() in \root\application\models\user_model.php on line 12

**user_model code**

```
<?php

 class User_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

public function create($email, $password)
{
    return $this->db->inset('user', [
        'email' => $email,
        'password' => $password

    ]);



}

public function delete()
{
    $this->db->where(['user_id' => $user_id]);
    return $this->db->delete('user');
}
}
```

**admin.php code**

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: password

Filename: controllers/admin.php

Line Number: 14

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Admin extends CI_Controller {


public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('admin');
}

public function create_user()
{
    $this->load->model('user_model');
    echo $this->user_model->create($_POST['email'], $_POST['password']);
}

public function delete_user($user_id)
{
    $this->load->model('user_model');
    $this->user_model->delete($user_id);
}
}
```

help me please

Comment: Surely you mean to `insert()` rather than `inset()`.

Comment: The `undefined index pasword` suggests your form does not actually have an input with `name='password'`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski thank you that works 

but new problem now

 A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: password

Filename: controllers/admin.php

Line Number: 14

Comment: My second comment addresses that - does your form actually have an input named `password`? There's no password key in `$_POST`.

Comment: <form action="<?=site_url('admin/create_user')?>" method="post">
     email: <input type="email" name="email"/> <br/>
  password: <input type="password" name='password' />
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the problem:
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: password

Filename: controllers/admin.php

### Line Number: 14

I have tried my best to run your code in CI, but I couldn't find out why;
But I noticed that the code in the "user_model.php" on the method "$this->db->insert()".
The parameters should be an Array, so please try this:

```
public function create($email, $password)
{
    return $this->db->inset('user', array(
        'email' => $email,
        'password' => $password,
        ),
    );
}
```

---

May this helps;